# Using PurePDF is it possible to view PDFs?

Tags: apache-flex, pdf, actionscript

Can you use PurePDF to view files or is the api only for writing them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the [PurePDF Project Page](http://code.google.com/p/purepdf/), reading and extracting information from PDFs is supported:

```
read existing pdf documents (extract strings, streams, images and all the informations from them).   See HelloWorldReader.as for an example
```

However, if you're looking to view / rasterize a PDF, that's a much more complicated task and doesn't look like it's supported as part of PurePDF.

Comment: Thanks Bilal. Yes viewing/rasterization is what I was talking about. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest converting the PDF into a swf file.  There are a number of projects out there (including free / open source) that convert pages into SWF files, including being able to still extract the text.   :D

Comment: I wanted to create a client side app to read PDF's on the Playbook since Adobe's reader on the Playbook is a piece of junk. :D

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can either navigate to the url of the PDF (maybe in an HTML component?) , OR a richer solution might be to use the open source flex paper : http://flexpaper.devaldi.com/